# Is there an easy way to create a partial \toprule?

Tags: tables, rules, booktabs

Is there a relatively simple equivalent to `\cmidrule` (a partial horisontal line in a table) but with the characteristics of a `\toprule`? It seems the booktabs package does not provide a `\ctoprule` command.

Comment: By "characteristics" of `\toprule`, I assume you mean its thickness. Have you tried `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6}`?

Comment: That's the trick! Care to make that an answer? I know it's a trivial thing, but I find SE sites a great place to find all those trivial things the brain can't quite keep track of ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By "characteristics of a `\toprule`?", I assume you mean the thickness of the line. To draw a `\cmidrule`, whose default weight is `\cmidrulewidth`, with the thickness of a `\toprule`, you'd type something like

```
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6}
```

---

*Addendum*: As @Manuel has pointed out in a comment, `\toprule` differs from `\cmidrule` (and `\midrule`) not only in terms of line thickness but also by not having vertical whitespace in the amount of `\aboverulesep` inserted *above* the line. If your "truncated toprule` should have no such whitespace, you'd need to write

```
 \addlinespace[-\aboverulesep] 
 \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6}
```

to achieve your objective.

Comment: To be a little nitpicking, egreg (IIRC) wrote an answe like this but with adjusted spacing. I think it was something like `\addlinespace[-\aboverulesep] \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6}`.

Comment: @Manuel - I interpreted the OP's objective as being interested mainly (exclusively?) in getting cmidrules to have the thickness of a `\toprule`. Let's see if the OP weighs in and states that that's not the correct interpretation.

Comment: I don't think people (necessarily) know toprule has different spacing. A toprule is a midrule with different thickness and different spacing, I just added the spacing (unless I did it wrong) in case you want to add it to your answer (I think its a good change anyways).

Comment: Question: In case I wanted to do the same but with `\bottomrule`, should I add something like `\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{3-6} \addlinespace[-\belowrulesep] ` ?

Comment: @Vicent - That looks right. Did you try it?

Comment: @Mico Yes, I tried it, and it seem it works.  :)