# Partial \bottomrule

Tags: rules, booktabs

Comments in the thread [Is there an easy way to create a partial \toprule?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254612/is-there-an-easy-way-to-create-a-partial-toprule) provide a solution for creating a "partial" `\toprule`. Is there a way to create an analogous partial `\bottomrule`?

I.e. what characteristic must be added to a `\cmidrule` to make it simulate the behaviour of `\bottomrule`?

Comment: You can use it. What details should differ?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 11):

Let's assume your `tabular`-like environment has 5 columns and that the "partial bottomrule" should span columns 2-4, with trimming on the left and the right. The following directives should work for you:

```
\cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](lr){2-4}
\addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]
```

---

*Addendum*: If your document calls for repeated uses of partial top and bottom rules, it's worth setting up dedicated macros; they're called `\partialtoprule` and `\partialbottomrule` in the following example. Note that the macros take 2 arguments: the first argument, if non-empty, indicates any trimming that should be performed. In the following screenshot, the first `tabular` environment employs standard `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` directives, while the second employs "partial" top and bottom rules. (The thin longer lines in the following screenshot are there just to indicate what's above and below the `tabular` environments.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\partialtoprule[2]{%
   \addlinespace[-\aboverulesep]
   \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](#1){#2}}
\newcommand\partialbottomrule[2]{%
   \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](#1){#2}
   \addlinespace[-\belowrulesep]}

\begin{document}

\hrule
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\toprule
   AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\hrule
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccc@{}}
\partialtoprule{r}{1-2}     % right-trimming only
   AAA & BBB & CCC & DDD & EEE \\
\partialbottomrule{lr}{3-4} % left- and right-trimming 
\end{tabular}
\hrule

\end{document}
```